# Using GUID string in JOIN condition messes up execution time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sqlperformance

I recognized a strange behavior. Given the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
JOIN bar ON bar.id = foo.bar_id AND bar.other_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Execution time on my server: ~120 ms, Reads: ~125000

When I rewrite the query like this:

```
DECLARE @other_id uniqueidentifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
SELECT * FROM foo
JOIN bar ON bar.id = foo.bar_id AND bar.other_id = @other_id
```

Execution time: ~6ms, Reads: ~140

Can anyone explain why the first query is so much slower? I assume the GUID string is converted over and over again in the query, but I would expect SQL server to be smart enough to not do this.

Comment: Can you show EP for the first query?

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: since both queries are same,i believe,the difference in execution time(second query taking time ) can be pointed out to few factors like Data may not be in cache  for the first time  .Are you seeing same behavior repeatedly

Comment: It's not a caching problem, I repeatedly get the same results and tested on two servers. Here's the plan for the first (slow) query: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJBak2-Ye, and here's the second that uses the declare: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJhO13bFl. They seem very different although the only difference is the declaration style of one variable.

Comment: Are you using Unique Identifiers on any of your Clustered indexes?

Comment: I managed to speed up the problematic query (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJBak2-Ye) by adding an index on items_servers with all the columns that are conditions in the query (serverID, subtype, online). It's now almost as fast as the other query (~15 ms), no high number of reads anymore. Anyhow I still don't understand why SQL server still insists on these completely different execution plans for both queries. Here's the new plan after adding the index: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJwQUbXFl

Comment: Sorry, I meant (serverID, schedule, online).

Comment: @needfulthing the execution plans are for a **different** query. Please post execution plans for the query you've posted here. The `WHERE` statements *do* affect how indexes are selected. If statistics aren't up to date, the optimizer may select different indexes. This also makes it hard for anyone unfamiliar with your system to see what is actually different.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I see the problem, the query above was meant to be symbolic for the problem I faced. What confused me was the fact that the where statements did not change at all but SQL server decided to use a complete different execution plan based on one variable defined inline or upfront with DECLARE. This might be hard to analyse without exactly knowing how MS SQL server decides to execute a query under the hood.

Comment: @needfulthing: If you want any real help with this you need to share your table structures and index structures. We need to know if unique identifiers are being stored in text fields. Also understanding the structure of covering indexes [_dta_index_items_servers_6_1810821513__K2_K6_K1_K3_4_5_12] would be useful. SQL Server's recommendations shouldn't always be blindly followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce your problem. And Dan Guzman (+1) was on the right lines. Here's a demo of what's going on:

Create a table and dataset with the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),Val UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
SELECT NEWID() FROM sys.columns
GO 30
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
SELECT TOP 1000 Val FROM dbo.Test
GO 30

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Test(ID)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx2 ON dbo.Test(Val)
GO
```

Now look at your statistics:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('dbo.test',IDX2)
```

In EQ_ROWS you will see whole numbers (a count of duplicates matching the Hi Key), In AVG_RANGE_ROWS you will see decimal averages (mean rows per distinct key)

Run the next statement to identify a key that is or isn't duplicated.

```
SELECT Val, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Test GROUP BY Val HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
SELECT Val, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Test GROUP BY Val HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you run the below code with a Non-Unique [Val] then the execution plans will be identical because SQL produces plans based on AVG_RANGE_ROWS.

If you run the code with a Unique [Val] then the Plans are slightly different, the Estimated number of rows changes, the query with the Parameter will use AVG_RANGE_ROWS, the query with the hard coded value will use EQ_ROWS. This difference can send the optimiser into producing a completely different plan on more complicated environments.

```
DECLARE @r UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'CE043987-62B5-4AA6-9BE7-0005F2B54A24' 

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test WHERE Val = @r

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test WHERE Val = 'CE043987-62B5-4AA6-9BE7-0005F2B54A24'
```

Comment: I tried out OPTION(RECOMPILE) but SQL insists on using the same execution plan.

Comment: You are insane :) Although I do not fully understand all the details I see the difference. My future practical solution will be to analyse the execution plan in question and add the index that speeds up the execution, if possible. Nevertheless it's interesting to see that small changes can have great influence on execution plans.

Answer (score 3):

The likely cause of the difference is different execution plans rather than repeated conversions from string. The much higher reads suggests this. Compare the plans to verify.

Generally, SQL Server will estimate row counts more accurately when the actual value is known during compilation and generate a good plan. With the variable, the estimate is based on averages rather than the stats histogram. Try updating statistics and run the first query again as this may be a symptom of stale stats.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Please do not mind that I chose pacreely's answer, I was able to reproduce the behavior with his example.

Comment: @needfulthing, no worries. I provided only a general answer without an example because I didn't want to make assumptions about you actual DDL.

Answer (score -1):

The first select executes the JOIN first, where many rows were probably found that matched the JOIN condition. The second condition after the AND then limited this result down to one row. Hence, nearly a full read of the two tables was executed.

The second select has both conditions looking for a single value constant defined as a variable. This would be particularly quick if the id for each table was the primary key for one or both tables.